# RAM, CPU, Disk limiter per user

Tags: users, disk-usage, cpu, ram

I recently bought a VPS server which is running ubuntu-16.04-x86_64. This VPS has 4 GB of RAM, 2 threads i7-6700K 4.00 GHz processor and 30 GB SSD.
Is there some way to easily reduce RAM usage, disk space, and CPU usage for users?

Comment: Have you looked at quota and cgroups?